# Vim like modal editing in answers and comments

Tags: discussion, feature-request, editing

As a Vim user I would like to do all of my typing in Vim or a Vim like environment. This being the Vim stack exchange, is it possible to make all the text input fields on this site Vim-like?

I don't know how possible this is, But, I am sure almost everyone would love to see this. Just a suggestion.

Answer (score 5):

Speaking personally, I wouldn't like to see it and would object strongly to the feature unless it was opt-in.

There are third-party solutions to providing a vim-like experience for your web browser, such as [vimperator](http://www.vimperator.org), [pterosaur](https://github.com/ardagnir/pterosaur), [vimium](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/vimium/dbepggeogbaibhgnhhndojpepiihcmeb), [TextAid](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/textaid/ppoadiihggafnhokfkpphojggcdigllp), [It's All Text](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/its-all-text/), and [Text Editor Anywhere](http://www.listary.com/text-editor-anywhere).

I've seen [r/vim discuss the topic on several occasions](https://www.reddit.com/r/vim/search?q=browser&restrict_sr=on). You may find something useful there as well.

Comment: Of course, Its going to be an opt in. You will use it if you want it. I have tried Vimperator and vimium and they are not really designed for typing. But, I don't get why you would object to it?

Comment: @DurgaSwaroop I like consistency within applications; I spend a lot of time on other SE sites and I'd find it annoying and disconnected to have to type as if I were using vim *here*, but not on those other sites, that's all.

Answer (score 3):

I don't work for Stack Exchange (I'm just a volunteer), but I can pretty much guarantee you that this feature will never be implemented. There are several good reasons for this, probably the most important is remaining a level of uniformity across SE sites.

If you want this you'll have to do this client-side. I believe there are several projects to create a "Vim-like textarea"; all you need to do is make a user script or extension to use it everywhere on the site.

Note that we already have a [vi-se GitHub repo](https://github.com/vi-se). Ping me if you (or anyone else) is interested in working on this and I'll make a new repo.

Comment: Thanks for recommending that repo! I just installed it, and I like it very much!